# PHP Date Difference with Custom Format

Tags: php

I'm facing some problem while calculating the difference between two dates because of Date Format, please help me to fix this issue.

Date 1 - (Format: d/m/Y)

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$date1 = date('d/m/Y');

//Output - 20/05/2020
```

Date 2 - (Format: d/m/Y)

```
$date2 - 01/27/2020
```

My Code -

```
$diff = abs($date2 - $date1);  
$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));  
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));  
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24)); 

// Print the result 
printf("%d years, %d months, %d days", $years, $months, $days);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to calculate days, month etc manually. There is already DateTime Class available in PHP which you can leverage.

```php
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '20/05/2020'); // Use $date1 = new DateTime('NOW'); For Current Time
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '25/05/2020');
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);

printf("%d years, %d months, %d days", $interval->y, $interval->m, $interval->d);
```

Official PHP Documentation: [PHP DateTime Class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: Thank You so much #Harish, its working perfectly :)

Comment: Glad to Hear. Please make use of the PHP Docs, if you want to play with Date More.

Answer (score 0):

First you shoud use date format(Format: Y/m/d) and second use strtotime to convert date to seconds because abs function working with numeric values. try following code :

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$date1 = strtotime(date('Y/m/d'));
$date2 = strtotime('2020/05/27'); 
$diff = abs($date2 - $date1);  
$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));  
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));  
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24)); 

// Print the result 
printf("%d years, %d months, %d days", $years, $months, $days);
```

Output :

```
0 years, 0 months, 7 days
```

Comment: In my Database, i have more than 10000+ entries, so its very difficult for me to change the date format at this moment.